# Cant access Elasticsearch with AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

As shown in the photo below, I can reach the localhost elasticsearch, however, when I try to reach it with AWS public url:9200, it denies my connection.

[image: Port opened and localhost elasticsearch reached]

May I know how to connect to the AWS server's elasticsearch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are running with default settings where elasticsearch is only bound to localhost. Which means that no one else than localhost can actually connect to it.

Read [Important Settings section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/important-settings.html#network.host).